# Error inflating class fragment Fragment WebView

Tags: android, fragment

I want to implement webView with fragment, the .xml is like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<webView
    android:id="@+id/webView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="450dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <webView
        android:id="@+id/webView02"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />
    <webView
        android:id="@+id/webView03"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the way I deal with the webview is like
     public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment{

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.selected,container,false);
    return view;    
}
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView1=(WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView01);
    String url="#######";
    String url1="####"; String url2="#######";
    webView1.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    webView1.loadUrl(url);
    WebView webView2=(WebView)getView().findViewById(R.id.webView02);
    WebView webView3=(WebView)getView().findViewById(R.id.webView03);

    webView2.loadUrl(url1);
    webView3.loadUrl(url2);
     }
     private class Callback extends WebViewClient{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        return(false);
    }

}
```

when I run the application, it shows error

```
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      start activity ComponentInfo{com.rulee.logintested/com.rulee.logintested.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at com.rulee.logintested.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  ... 11 more
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at com.rulee.logintested.SelectionFragment.onCreate(SelectionFragment.java:38)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1437)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
  08-01 18:45:39.426: E/AndroidRuntime(27086):  ... 20 more
```

But when I change the .xml, change the webView into a simple TextView, and delete the code dealing with the webView, the error fixed.
Can anybody offer me some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you commented out  //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Hi, since in the method onCreateView(),View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.selected,container,false);

Comment: You have a NPE at SelectionFragment.onCreate(SelectionFragment.java:38)

Comment: Which line is that in your code?

Comment: since setContentView is the method only when the class extends Activity, right now, my class extends Fragment, since I want to implement webView with Fragment.

Comment: I deleted the onCreate method in SelectionFragment, the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

WebView is case-sensitive and you need CamelCase. So change your first w into a W.